# How to translate "aKernel32_dll_0: unicode 0, <KERNEL.32>, 0" into a legal declaration?

Tags: winapi, assembly, reverse-engineering, ida, kernel32

I use IDA Pro to disassemble SPEC 2006 binaries on Windows 7 32 bit.

It generates a variable declared like this:

```
aKernel32_dll_0 unicode 0, <KERNEL32.DLL>,0
```

In the .text section, I find usage of this variable like this:

```
push    offset aKernel32_dll_0
call    ds:__imp__GetModuleHandleW@4
......
```

What I am trying to do is to make these code/data reassemble.

So my questions are:

1. So basically declaration like  **aKernel32_dll_0 unicode 0, ,0 ** can not be directly reassembled by masm/nasm, how should I adjust it?
2. I simply adjust it into **aKernel32_dll_0 dd 0** and the code is like this:

[image]

and it would run into a strange situation every time after  **call    ds:__imp__GetModuleHandleW@4**

Comparing to the original binary using Ollydbg:

[image]

So it seems that aKernel32_dll_0  is actually a extern variable? So is the correct way  **delete the declaration and extern declare this variable?** If so, then what is the name of this variable? I don't think it is aKernel32_dll_0 as it looks like a random name generated by IDA Pro.

Could anyone give me some help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could of course just copy whatever bytes are there in your source material as a `DB` array.
That said, we know `GetModuleHandleW` takes an unicode module name as argument. In nasm syntax it could look like:

```
aKernel32_dll_0 DW __utf16__('KERNEL32.DLL'), 0
```

Comment: `masm` doesn't seem to support utf16 out of the box, but there are macro libraries that do. For this simple ascii string however you can just insert 0 bytes manually, like `aKernel32_dll_0 DB 'K', 0, 'E', 0 ...` you get the idea. Should end with 3 zeroes (one is the high byte of the last wchar, the other two are the terminators). Or, you could store this as ansi and switch the function call to use `GetModuleHandleA`.